# Finding sequence with $a_n - a_{n+1} = a_{n+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Have to construct a sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots$ whose elements are positive such that $a_0 =1$ and $a_n - a_{n+1} = a_{n+2}$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$

Have tried a few approaches but nothing working.

Comment: You need only to choose $a_2$. Or, you can only choose $a_2$.

Comment: $$  a_n = \left(  \frac{ \sqrt 5 - 1}{2}  \right)^n $$

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients

Answer (score 2):

To study sequences type :
$$x_{n + 1} = a x_{n + 1} + b x_n$$
consider the associated equation :
$$t^2 = a t + b$$
If the equation has :

1. Two different solutions $r$ and $s$ then :
   $$\exists A, B \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x_n = A r^n + B s^n$$
2. One solution $r$ then :
   $$\exists A, B \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x_n = (A n + B) r^n$$
3. Two different complexe conjugate solutions $r e^{i \theta}$ and $r e^{-i \theta}$ then :
   $$\exists A, B \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x_n = r^n (A \cos n \theta + B \sin n \theta)$$

To determine $A$ and $B$ you need two values of $x_n$, for example $x_0$ and $x_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n:=(-1)^na_n$. We have

$$f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_n,$$ which is the Fibonacci recurrence. From Binet's formula, we recall that the Fibonacci numbers are the sum of a growing exponential $\phi^n$ and and alternating one, $(-\phi)^{-n}$.

Hence,

$$a_n=\phi^{-n}$$ can do.